# How to remove nested elements in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have an HTML structure like this

```
body
  svg
     g
      path d
      circle  (class=circles)
     g
      path d
      circle  (class=circles)
     g
     path d
     g
     path d
     g
      path d
      circle (class=circles)
```

I want to remove all circles from body->svg->g->circle with class=circles .
Some "g" tags have circles with class as "circles".

Please guide me how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in one line using a DOM selector:

```
d3.selectAll("circle.circles").remove();
```

Comment: yes it is working like charm.please tell me the logic.And I have seen that you have very good knowledge of d3.js.Please recommend some book.

Comment: You select `circle` elements with class `circles` -- this is just the syntax to express this. I haven't read any of the books on D3, so I can't recommend any.

Comment: d3.selectAll("circle") was not working.how come your way worked?and lets say I have not set class attributes on circles,then how could I select the nested circles

Comment: The `.circles` tells it to select only elements with this class. If there's no class, you can't select just those.

Comment: What is the logic that selectAll("circle"),selectAll(".circle") doesn't work ,but selectÄll("cicle.circles") works?

Comment: `d3.selectAll("circle").selectAll(".circles")` should work. Note `.circles` and not `.circle`.

Comment: I was debugging the code and found that it is only removing circles. and leaves empty g tag.How do I remove that g also in which circle is defined.

Comment: Does the `g` element have a specific class? `d3.selectAll("g.circles").remove();`